# Can prepared statements be enabled out of the box?

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra, scylla

I would like to make use of prepared statements when executing `CQL` in my application. This functionality looks to be provided by the `ReactiveCqlTemplate` class, which I have passed into the `ReactiveCassandraTemplate` in my Cassandra configuration here:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableReactiveCassandraRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.my.app",
        includeFilters = {
                @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = {ScyllaPersonRepository.class})
        })
public class CassandraConfiguration extends AbstractReactiveCassandraConfiguration {

    @Value("${cassandra.host}")
    private String cassandraHost;

    @Value("${cassandra.connections}")
    private Integer cassandraConnections;

    @Override
    public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster() {
        PoolingOptions poolingOptions = new PoolingOptions()
                .setCoreConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL,  cassandraConnections)
                .setMaxConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL, cassandraConnections*2);

        CassandraClusterFactoryBean bean = super.cluster();
        bean.setJmxReportingEnabled(false);
        bean.setPoolingOptions(poolingOptions);
        bean.setLoadBalancingPolicy(new TokenAwarePolicy(new RoundRobinPolicy()));

        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public ReactiveCassandraTemplate reactiveCassandraTemplate() {
        return new ReactiveCassandraTemplate(reactiveCqlTemplate(), cassandraConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraEntityInformation getCassandraEntityInformation(CassandraOperations cassandraTemplate) {
        CassandraPersistentEntity<Person> entity =
                (CassandraPersistentEntity<Person>)
                        cassandraTemplate
                                .getConverter()
                                .getMappingContext()
                                .getRequiredPersistentEntity(Person.class);
        return new MappingCassandraEntityInformation<>(entity, cassandraTemplate.getConverter());
    }

    @Override
    public SchemaAction getSchemaAction() {
        return SchemaAction.CREATE_IF_NOT_EXISTS;
    }

    public String getContactPoints() {
        return cassandraHost;
    }

    public String getKeyspaceName() {
        return "mykeyspace";
    }
}
```

This is the `ScyllaPersonRepository` referenced in my Cassandra configuration filters.

```java
public interface ScyllaPersonRepository extends ReactiveCassandraRepository<Person, PersonKey> {
    @Query("select id, name from persons where id = ?0")
    Flux<Object> findPersonById(@Param("id") String id);
}
```

After executing a few queries, the CQL Non-Prepared statements metric in my [Scylla Monitoring Dashboard](https://docs.scylladb.com/operating-scylla/monitoring/) showed that I'm not using prepared statements at all.

I was able to use prepared statements after followed the documentation [here](https://lankydan.dev/2018/10/23/cached-prepared-statements-with-spring-data-cassandra) which walked me through creating the `CQL` myself.

```java
public class ScyllaPersonRepository extends SimpleReactiveCassandraRepository<Person, PersonKey> {
    private final Session session;
    private final CassandraEntityInformation<Person, PersonKey> entityInformation;
    private final ReactiveCassandraTemplate cassandraTemplate;
    private final PreparedStatementCache cache = PreparedStatementCache.create();

    public ScyllaPersonRepository(
            Session session,
            CassandraEntityInformation<Person, PersonKey> entityInformation,
            ReactiveCassandraTemplate cassandraTemplate
    ) {
        super(entityInformation, cassandraTemplate);
        this.session = session;
        this.entityInformation = entityInformation;
        this.cassandraTemplate = cassandraTemplate;
    }

    public Flux<ScyllaUser> findSegmentsById(String id) {
        return cassandraTemplate
                .getReactiveCqlOperations()
                .query(
                        findPersonByIdQuery(id),
                        (row, rowNum) -> convert(row)
                );
    }

    private BoundStatement findPersonByIdQuery(String id) {
        return CachedPreparedStatementCreator.of(
                cache,
                QueryBuilder.select()
                        .column("id")
                        .column("name")
                        .from("persons")
                        .where(QueryBuilder.eq("id", QueryBuilder.bindMarker("id"))))
                .createPreparedStatement(session)
                .bind()
                .setString("id", id);
    }

    private Person convert(Row row) {
        return new Person(
                row.getString("id"),
                row.getString("name"));
    }
}
```

But, I would really like the ORM to handle that all for me. Is it possible to configure this behaviour out of the box, so that I don't need to manually write the `CQL` myself but instead just enable it as an option in my Cassandra Configuration and get the ORM to orchestrate it all behind the scenes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frankly, I think this is a bug(request for enhancement) and it should be filed in Springs Jira.
It seems the repository simply doesn't support this out of box(nor did I find any config option how to flip it, but I might have missed it).

Actually, my theory was correct:
https://jira.spring.io/projects/DATACASS/issues/DATACASS-578?filter=allopenissues
so just add yourself and try to ask them for resolution.